# PHP: Update DB Parse Error

Tags: php, sql, parsing, sql-update, syntax-error

I a creating a form where the user can update previously entered information in fields relative to an ID field.

However, I am getting a parse syntax error when using the HEREDOC method of displaying the modifications to the code.

My error displayed looks like this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/serverside/phptut/update.php on
>   line 24

For reference my script on 24 onward looks like this:

```
echo<<<EOD 
    <b>The new record looks like this:</b>
    Email: $email<br/>
    First: $first<br/>
    Last: $last<br/>
    Status: $status<br/>
EOD;
```

And for further reference my code in totality is this

```
<?php
include "dbinfo.php";
//gets the variables from form submitted
$id = $_POST[id];
$email = $_POST[email];
$first = $_POST[first];
$last = $_POST[last];
$status = $_POST[status];

//sets the values where the ID is equal to what was passed in 
$sql = "UPDATE contacts SET
email = '$email',
first ='$first',
last = '$last',
phone ='$phone'
where ID = '$id' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
//excute

//print what the new one looks like
echo '<html><head><title>Updated Results</title></head><body>';
include ("header.php");
echo<<<EOD 
    <b>The new record looks like this:</b>
    Email: $email<br/>
    First: $first<br/>
    Last: $last<br/>
    Status: $status<br/>
EOD;

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a space at the end of `echo<<<EOD` remove it and it will work, just as Phil stated below.

Comment: Well, when I copied the OP's code, it was a space. @Phil least, that's what it showed up as, as single character if I can say.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Never mind, `vi` identified it as `trail` which I took to mean a different character. It is in fact a trailing space

Comment: I learned something new tonight, noted. @Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: `<<<`. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline.

There should not be a space between `<<<` and the identifier and there should only be a newline after. You a single, trailing space character after `<<<EOD`.

Working demo here - http://codepad.org/Y2vxavDB

Also, please be aware that the MySQL extension has been deprecated. You should be using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I edited the space, it made no difference.

Comment: @rsheeler You appear to have a tab or some other whitespace character (other than a newline) after `<<<EOD`

Comment: @Phil I figured it out for myself, and you're right. The OP obviously has a white space after `EOD` and/or after the end. Actually I'm glad you didn't tell me the "why", because I actually like to figure things out for myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line.

Here is another Example http://codepad.org/FobMK0AL

```
<?php
echo<<<EOD
<b>The new record looks like this:</b>
Email: $email<br/>
First: $first<br/>
Last: $last<br/>
Status: $status<br/>
EOD;

?>
```